# This Realm instance has already been closed

Tags: android, realm

I am developing a cv app and use realm for saving retrofit responses, but I am getting the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone, PID: 5400
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
    at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:435)
    at io.realm.Realm.where(Realm.java:1368)
    at activity.drawer.navigation.com.kitabsawticlone.IntroductionItem$1.onResponse(IntroductionItem.java:60)
```

My IntroductionItem.java class:

```
public class IntroductionItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RealmList<Introduction> introductionList;

    public IntroductionAdapter adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.introduction);
        KitabInterface kitabInterface = ApiClient.getApiService();
        Call<KitabSawti> call = kitabInterface.getIntroduction();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<KitabSawti>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<KitabSawti> call, Response<KitabSawti> response) {
                introductionList = response.body().getIntroduction();
                Realm.init(IntroductionItem.this);

                RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                        .name("overview.realm")
                        .schemaVersion(1)
                        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                        .build();
                Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);


                // add response to realm database
                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(introductionList);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();


// programmatically check : data is inserted in to realm or not

                int notesCount = realm.where(KitabSawti.class).findAll().size();
                int notesCount2 = realm.where(Introduction.class).findAll().size();


                Log.d("my first", String.valueOf(notesCount));
                Log.d("my second", String.valueOf(notesCount2));


                RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                adapter = new IntroductionAdapter(IntroductionItem.this, introductionList); // changes
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<KitabSawti> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `realm.close();` and place it on onStop() or somewhere else.

Comment: @LeoPolozo Where exactly I have to close it

Comment: You need to close it when you are done with the realm instance. In your case, it can be the last line of onResponse()

Answer (score 1):

You are closing realm when you use `realm.close();`, move this line to the end of your call. Like this:

```
public class IntroductionItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RealmList<Introduction> introductionList;

    public IntroductionAdapter adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.introduction);
        KitabInterface kitabInterface = ApiClient.getApiService();
        Call<KitabSawti> call = kitabInterface.getIntroduction();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<KitabSawti>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<KitabSawti> call, Response<KitabSawti> response) {
                introductionList = response.body().getIntroduction();
                Realm.init(IntroductionItem.this);

                RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                        .name("overview.realm")
                        .schemaVersion(1)
                        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                        .build();
                Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);


                // add response to realm database
                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(introductionList);
                realm.commitTransaction();



// programmatically check : data is inserted in to realm or not

                int notesCount = realm.where(KitabSawti.class).findAll().size();
                int notesCount2 = realm.where(Introduction.class).findAll().size();


                Log.d("my first", String.valueOf(notesCount));
                Log.d("my second", String.valueOf(notesCount2));


                RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                adapter = new IntroductionAdapter(IntroductionItem.this, introductionList); // changes
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                realm.close();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<KitabSawti> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Please mark your quesiton as answered.

Comment: Polozo it was implemented correctly I mean it should work when app is offline it is my first time using realm thanks for your answer